# What is the logic behind the behaviour of reg in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, hdl

I know *SystemVerilog* and now I'm trying to learn pure *Verilog*. I find the way `reg` works to be rather odd. I thought `wire` is used for signals that are continuously driven like the output of combinational logic, and `reg` is used for signals that can retain their state, such as the output of flip flops or latches.

However I read that any signal assigned inside of an `always` block must be `reg`. Even if the behavior is modeling combinational logic, like in a `case` statement, which leads to the following weird situation:

Example a:

```
assign y = s ? a : b;
```

Example b:

```
always @* begin
    if (s)
         y = a;
    else
         y = b;
end
```

In *example a*  `y` would be `wire` whereas in *example b* `y` must be `reg`. However they both describe the same thing. My only explanation for this is that within a combinational `always` it is possible to accidentally leave no specified output for some inputs, implying a latch which should be `reg` so they force it to always be `reg`.

Please help me understand the reasoning for how `reg` works in *Verilog*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyword `reg` in Verilog is a misnomer and why it was renamed to `logic` in SystemVerilog. It is just a 4-state data type for a variable that could be interpreted as a hardware register or combinational signal.

The thing that makes it confusing for people starting in SystemVerilog and having to go back to Verilog is the single continuous driver rule. Wires are meant to handle multiple drivers with built-in resolution functions, but most signals only have a single driver. SystemVerilog made an exception so that variables could be continuously driven by a single driver. Then you can use variables for most everything only reverting to wires when you needed multiple drivers, like a bidirectional bus.

See [this webpage](https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/verificationhorizons/2013/05/03/wire-vs-reg/) for more explicit details.